# MooTools return undefined object

Tags: mootools

I have predefine MooTools.js and some another javascript called moomenu for dropdown...
However i could test the code and i come to know that "typeof(MooTool)" return undefined...
I am new to MooTool so will any body please tell me what happens there???

Comment: How did you include the mootools.js file?

Comment: `MooTool` ought to be plural. Try `typeof(MooTools)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your calling it "MooTool" instead of "MooTools"; however, if you look at the source, `var MooTools` only refers to an object with the version and build information. If you're trying to select an element, you want to look at the $ and $$ functions of the Element object:

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element